# Calculate sum, avg, max and min

Tags: mysql

I have the following table on SQL:

[image]

If you notice on the column 'timeroperador' there are duplicated values
I would like to have a procedure to find these duplicated values,calculate and return the avg, max, min and sum of the column 'timertempo'. is that possible? I know that I can do it like this:

```
select avg(timertempo) from tempo where timeroperador = 'Nonato'
```

and so on, by informing the names. But I don't want to keep informing the names. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the avg, max, min, and sum for groups with multiple entries you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. For example:

```
select
  timeroperador, 
  avg(timertempo),
  max(timertempo),
  min(timertempo),
  sum(timertempo)
from tempo 
group by timeroperador
having count(*) > 1
```